# Using goto statement for loop

Tags: c, goto, temperature

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char choice;
    float x,y;

    start:
    printf("[c] Converts Celsius -> Fahrenheit\n[f] Converts Fahrenheit -> Celsius\n\n\n");
    printf("Enter Choice: ");
    scanf("%c",&choice);
    if (choice!='c' || choice!='f' || choice!='x') {
            printf("Wrong Choice: Try Again!");
            goto start;

        } if (choice!=x)
          printf("Input Value: ");
          scanf("%f",&x);
                if (choice =='c')
                    y = 1.8 * x + 32
                else
                    y = (x-32) * (5/9)
          printf("Result: %.2f",y);
          exit:

    return 0;
}
```

My instructor posted this but when I tried it, it have errors, need help to fix it.

Comment: What errors? What did you try? What do you expect?

Comment: Using `goto` is considered okay in some certain situations. Using it instead of a *loop* is not one of those situations. Why don't you use loops?

Comment: One obvious problem is the `if` statement that checks `choice`.  The condition is clearly always true:  It can't be equal to `c`, `f`, and `x` all at the same time, and the test is that if it's not equal to *any* of them, do something.  You can replace it with `if (1)` if that's really your intent.

Comment: And a general tip regarding reading single characters using [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf): Almost always you want to skip leading white-space, or you will read possible newlines which often is not wanted. Try doing `scanf(" %c", &choice);`, note the space in `" %c"`.

Comment: Instantly get a new instructor. Such code should be reason to get fired. There are rare acceptable reasons to use `goto`; this is definitively none of them.

Comment: @Olaf perhaps the assignment was "what is wrong with this code and fix it".

Comment: @BartFriederichs: Iff(!) that is true, it still is bad idea, as it implies using `goto` is bad juju. (I know many people think so)

Comment: @Olaf it might be implying `goto` is bad in this case, which it is. Nothing wrong with that, I'd say.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: I did not write different, did I?

Comment: The title was nonsense. `goto` is no computational statement.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite some things wrong with this code:

1. Using `goto` instead of a `while` loop is not the way to make this.
2. Your second `if` (`if (choice != x)`) is missing braces. This way only the first statement is executed if true. The rest is *always* executed.
3. You are missing semicolons `;` after your calculations.
4. Your boolean logic in the first `if` is incorrect.
5. In your second `if` you are comparing against a variable, instead of a fixed value.
6. Your Fahrenheit-to-Celsius arithmetic is incorrect.

Hope these tips help you. I won't post the correct code, that's up to you as you are still learning ;-).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should forget that there is the `goto` statement in C.

All programs that contained a `goto` statement and I saw including some IBM's source code had numerous bugs related to `goto` statements.

The `goto` statement makes programs difficult to read and more difficult to maintain and modify them.

Using the `goto` statement is the same as traffic violatins.:)

Instead of this code snippet

```
start:
printf("[c] Converts Celsius -> Fahrenheit\n[f] Converts Fahrenheit -> Celsius\n\n\n");
printf("Enter Choice: ");
scanf("%c",&choice);
if (choice!='c' || choice!='f' || choice!='x') {
        printf("Wrong Choice: Try Again!");
        goto start;

    }
```

that at least has an invalid condition in the if statement

```
if (choice!='c' || choice!='f' || choice!='x')
```

instead of valid

```
if (choice!='c' && choice!='f' && choice!='x')
```

You could write for example

```
enum { Celsius = 'c', Fahrenheit = 'f', Exit = 'x' };
char choice;
int valid_input;

do
{
    printf( "[c] Converts Celsius -> Fahrenheit\n"
            "[f] Converts Fahrenheit -> Celsius\n"
            "[x] Exit\n\n" );

    printf( "Enter Choice: " );

    if ( scanf( "%c ", &choice ) != 1 ) choice = Exit;

    valid_input = choice == Celsius || choice == Fahrenheit || choice == Exit;

    if ( !valid_input ) puts( "Wrong Choice: Try Again!\n" );
} while ( !valid_input );
```

Your program contains numerous bugs. Insetad of to list them I will show how
the program could be written

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{    
    enum { Celsius = 'c', Fahrenheit = 'f', Exit = 'x' };
    char choice;
    int valid_input;

    do
    {
        printf( "[c] Converts Celsius -> Fahrenheit\n"
                "[f] Converts Fahrenheit -> Celsius\n"
                "[x] Exit\n\n" );

        printf( "Enter Choice: " );

        if ( scanf( "%c ", &choice ) != 1 ) choice = Exit;

        valid_input = choice == Celsius || choice == Fahrenheit || choice == Exit;

        if ( !valid_input ) puts( "Wrong Choice: Try Again!\n" );
    } while ( !valid_input );


    switch( choice )
    {
        float x, y;

        case Celsius: case Fahrenheit:
            printf( "Input Value: " );
            if ( scanf( "%f", &x ) == 1 )
            {                
                if ( choice == Celsius )
                    y = 1.8 * x + 32;
                else
                    y = ( x - 32 ) * ( 5.0f / 9.0f );
                printf( "Result: %.2f\n", y );
            }                
        case Exit:
            puts( "Bye!" );
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

if to enter sequentially

```
c 20 x
```

then the output will look like

```
[c] Converts Celsius -> Fahrenheit
[f] Converts Fahrenheit -> Celsius
[x] Exit

Enter Choice: c
Input Value: 20
Result: 68.00
Bye!
```

Comment: Guys, I put a wrong Title.

It should be TEMPERATURE CONVERTER USING GOTO STATEMENT
not in loop. Sorry.